# Asymptotic Behaviors of Hypergeometric function for two large parameters

Tags: limits, asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I am studying the asymptotic behaviors of the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ by reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05146.pdf) paper. However, the paper does not mention the case when $b$ and $c$ are large. I tried looking online for sources that would consider the case I am interested in. What would be the asymptotic formula for this case?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is there a relation between the ways $b$ and $c$ are approaching infinity? Note that large $b$ and $c$ is the same as large $a$ and $c$.

Comment: @Gary b is negative and c is positive.

Comment: Are they tending to infinity at the same rate? Do you have a more specific case in mind? For example, $F(a, -n+\beta;n+\gamma;z)$ with fixed $\beta, \gamma$ and $ n \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Garry Let's say $F(a, 1 - n, n+2, z)$ and $n \to \infty$

Comment: We have $$
{}_2F_1(a, -n+\beta ;n+\gamma ;z) = (1 - z)^{ - a} {}_2F_1 \!\left( {a,2n - \beta  + \gamma ;n + \gamma ;\frac{z}{{z - 1}}} \right)\\ = (1 - z)^{ - a} {}_2F_1\! \left( {2n - \beta  + \gamma ,a;n + \gamma ;\frac{z}{{z - 1}}} \right).
$$ Thus, this is 2.2.2 in the paper you are considering. It seems that something is not correct in $(2.28)$ regarding the algebraic singularities with respect to $z$. They assume $|z|>1/\varepsilon$ but the ${}_2F_1$ is not analytic in such a domain. In some cases, $(2.28)$ returns large imaginary values when the function is in fact real valued.

Comment: You may consider https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08794.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.01945.pdf

Comment: @Gary Thank you very much for the sources